# Changing date format of a dataframe /column

Tags: python, dataframe, date, updates, epoch

for time in df[col]:
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time))

Why is not updating directly the dataframe df[col]? My aim is to update one column of a data frame with new date format.

Answer (score 0):

I solved; I creat a list and update the related column of the dataframe with the list.

a_list=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time))
df[col]=a_list

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```py
df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col].astype(int))
```